# PowerShell: How Do I insert $env:HOSTNAME/$env:Computer) into a text file, as part of a text replacement?

Tags: powershell, text, replace

I have a long custom application config file for an application that runs on workstations, with some text elements that have to be changed manually from system to system.

This script is an attempt to make my life easier -

```
$content = Get-Content("C:\file.text")
$content = $content.replace("%DoTheThing?%","TRUE")
$content = $content.replace("%Place%","SpecificPlace")
$content = $content.replace("%SystemName%",$env:HOSTNAME)
$content = Set-Content("C:\file.text")
```

When I execute the script, the first text items get replaced correctly, the third gets deleted, instead of replaced. Being new to Power Shell, How do I correct this - such that the actual system name is replacing the %SystemName% section?

Comment: `$Env:HOSTNAME` isn't an environment variable.  Try `$Env:COMPUTERNAME`

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `$env:HOSTNAME` is not a valid environment variable.
To get a list of all environment variables you can run `Get-ChildItem Env:`
`$Env:COMPUTERNAME` should do the trick, so change it to this:

```
$content = Get-Content("C:\file.text")
$content = $content.replace("%DoTheThing?%","TRUE")
$content = $content.replace("%Place%","SpecificPlace")
$content = $content.replace("%SystemName%",$Env:COMPUTERNAME)
$content = Set-Content("C:\file.text")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add up, here are the three possible ways to get your current computername with their use in your `replace` call:

**Using old CMD utilities:**

```
hostname
$content = $content.replace("%SystemName%","$(hostname)")
```

**Using the local enviroment-variables:**

```
$Env:ComputerName
$content = $content.replace("%SystemName%",$Env:COMPUTERNAME)
```

**Using the .Net DNS Class-Object and the therefor given method to get your hostname:**

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
$content = $content.replace("%SystemName%",[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName())
```

Comment: Can you explain the 3rd option?

Comment: [System.Net.Dns] is a .NET Class. Since Powershell builds on .NET you can use .NET classes in Powershell. With .NET classes you call a method on the class. So basically you say, I want to use the class [System.Net.Dns] and on this class you want to use the method GetHostName which gets you the hostname.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know they were kind of self-explaining. Will edit in a few minutes.

Comment: I'm new to power shell, I think the fault is mine. I know the system name, but I want to be able to insert the script element to pull the system name from the system, and replace the text in the config file (for the record, it's an XML file) ... so that I don't have to do it manually every time a change is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So I went an alternate route to accomplish my task. I tried all the various was submitted first, and then stumbled on the System.IO.File method which worked beautifully:

```
$ConfigPath = "C:\FOLDER\APP\VER\File.CONFIG"

$LoadFromConfig = 
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($ConfigPath).Replace("%LOAD_FROM_CONFIG%","TRUE")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($ConfigPath,$LoadFromConfig)

$DestinationCode = 
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($ConfigPath).Replace("%Destination_Code%","BBB")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($ConfigPath,$DestinationCode)

$KioskID =  
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($ConfigPath).Replace("%KIOSK_ID%",$Env:COMPUTERNAME)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($ConfigPath,$KioskID)
```